# Voice Activation Microphone

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, voice, teamspeak

I wondered if any of you knew any ways to activate your microphone on a specific level of volume, so that it will disable if the volume is lower than X. 
If any of you have TeamSpeak, it's built in there, that's what I mean, i just wondered if any of you knew a thing that would perhaps set up a new device that could be used in any program. 
I'm using alot of skype, so just for skype would be great enough.

Thanks :)

EDIT: Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: I'm no expert, but I assume this requires a special bit of hardware if you want it to be "built-in" to Windows 7. As far as I know, Windows 7 doesn't have any built-in functionality for this. Software like TeamSpeak has this capability because it was designed for the software (hence why some other programs like Skype don't have this feature). I couldn't find anything while searching around the web... hopefully someone has a solution, I really like this idea :)

Comment: Skype does not have this feature at this time.

Comment: If you set up a custom driver for a microphone that has the input of the sound that the software gives it from the original microphone, it would be possible.